# ¿Cómo separo eventos de un control de usuario insertado varias veces? C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, usercontrol, forms-events

¡Buenos días!
Mi problema es el siguiente:
Tengo una base de datos que alberga **n** cantidad de dispositivos. Y en un formulario, llamo a un **Control de Usuario** varias veces, en tiempo de ejecución; uno para cada dispositivo. Los datos cargan como deberían; asignando una *Label* con el nombre del dispositivo, etc. Sin embargo, tengo un evento con un botón, este botón debería información según el control de usuario correspondiente a un dispositivo; pero el problema es que sólo guarda información del dispositivo correspondiente al último control de usuario agregado (el cuál es el último en la base de datos). Ejemplo: Estoy en el control correspondiente al dispositivo de nombre "XBOX1"; pero al hacer click en el botón guarda los datos del "XBOX5"; y sucede en todos los controles, todos guardarán solamente lo del "XBOX5".

[image: Ctrol correspondiente]

[image: Datos del ultimo dispositivo].

Abajo pondré el código que estoy manejando, por el momento está sucio, pero no logro poder evitarme ese problema.
**Código donde creo los controles de usuario:**

```
public void ObtenerDatosTablas(string consultas, string tablas, Panel forma)
        {
            QDispositivos = 0;
            ldispositivos.Clear();
            var ds = new DataSet();
            ds = _base.ObtenerDatos(consultas,tablas);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];

             QDispositivos = int.Parse(_base.ConsultaRetorno("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dispositivo;"));

            if (QDispositivos > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    var Datos = new EntidadDispositivos();
                    Datos.Numero = count;
                    Datos.IDdispositivo = row["idDispositivo"].ToString();
                    ldispositivos.Add(Datos);
                    count++;
                }
                count = 0;
                foreach (var item in ldispositivos)
                {
                    MostrarRenta(item.IDdispositivo, forma);
                }
            }
        }
        public void MostrarRenta(string dato, Panel forma)
        {
            if (x < 1100 )
            {
                AddCtrlPanel(dato, forma);
                x += 300;
            }
            else
            {
                y += 350;
                x = 25;
                AddCtrlPanel(dato, forma);
                
            }
            count++;

        }
        void AddCtrlPanel(string dato, Panel forma)
        {
            mc = new UserControl1(dato, userOn, count);
            mc.Name = "control" + count.ToString();
            mc.Location = new Point(x, y);
            
            mc.click_btnIniciar += new EventHandler(_iniciar);
            mc.click_btnParar += new EventHandler(_parar);
            forma.Controls.Add(mc);
        } 
 public void GuardarRenta(string Dispositivo, string tiempo, string comentario, string estado, string rentador, string fecha, string horai, string horaf, double total)
        {
            _base.Consultar(string.Format("INSERT INTO renta VALUES (null,'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}',{8});", Dispositivo, tiempo, comentario, estado, rentador, fecha, horai, horaf, total));

        }
        private void _parar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mc.lblNombreDisp.Text);

            mc.costoDisp = PrecioDispositivo(mc.lblNombreDisp.Text);
            GuardarRenta(mc.lblNombreDisp.Text, mc.tiempoIngresado.ToString(),mc.txtComentario.Text,mc.Estado,mc.txtRentador.Text,mc.Fecha,mc.HoraI,mc.HoraF,mc.total); ;
        
        }

        private void _iniciar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

**Código del Control de usuario **

```
namespace UserC
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public string Comentario = "", Rentador = "", HoraI = "", HoraF = "", Total = "", Estado = "Desactivado", Fecha = "";
        public int contador = 0, contadorDetenido = 0, Tiempo = 0, NControl = 0;
        public double total = 0, tiempoIngresado = 0, costoDisp = 0;
        public bool DetenidoNatural = false;

        private void tmrTiempo_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (contador < Tiempo)
            {
                lbltiempo.Text = (int.Parse(lbltiempo.Text)-1).ToString();
                contador++;
            }
            else
            {
                Detener();
                EjecutarDatos();
                DetenidoNatural = true;
                btnParar.Click += new EventHandler(btnParar_Click);
            }
            
        }

        public UserControl1(string nombreDisp, string rentador, int nControl)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            btnParar.Enabled = false;
            lblNombreDisp.Text = nombreDisp;
            txtRentador.Text = rentador;
            NControl = nControl;
        }

        public EventHandler click_btnIniciar;
        public EventHandler click_btnParar;
        public double CalcularTotal(double costodisp, double tiempo)
        {


            double total = costodisp / 60 * tiempo;

            return total;
        }
        void EjecutarDatos()
        {
           total=
            CalcularTotal(costoDisp, tiempoIngresado);
            txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();
        }
        void Iniciar()
        {
            //Estados
            Estado = "Activado";
            DetenidoNatural = false;
            lbltiempo.Text = (int.Parse(txtTiempo.Text)*60).ToString();
            Tiempo = int.Parse(txtTiempo.Text)*60;
            tiempoIngresado = Tiempo;
            total = 0;
            HoraI = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt");
            HoraF = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(txtTiempo.Text)).ToString("hh:mm tt");
            Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            //Timer
            txtTiempo.Enabled = false;
            tmrTiempo.Enabled = true;
            tmrTiempo.Start();

            //Habilitados
            btnIniciar.Enabled = false;
            btnParar.Enabled = true;

            //textbobex
            txtHoraI.Text = HoraI;
            txtHoraF.Text = HoraF;
            
        }
        void Detener()
        {
            //Estados
            Estado = "Desactivado";
            lbltiempo.Text = 0.ToString();
            //Timer
            txtTiempo.Enabled = true;
            tmrTiempo.Enabled = false;
            tmrTiempo.Stop();
            Tiempo = 0;
            contador = 0;

            //Habilitados
            btnIniciar.Enabled = true;
            btnParar.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //aqui
            
            

            if (click_btnIniciar != null)
            {
                click_btnIniciar(this, e);
                Iniciar();

            }
        }

        private void btnParar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //aqui
            
           if (click_btnParar != null)
            {
                click_btnParar(this, e);
                tiempoIngresado = contador / 60;

                Detener();
                if (DetenidoNatural == true)
                {
                    Estado = "Desactivado";
                }
                else
                {
                    Estado = "Parado por rentador";
                }

                EjecutarDatos();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y donde esta el codigo del boton guardar...

Comment: Buenas; los botones sólo los uso para guardar consultas (por el momento estan trabajando con código "sucio" con datos públicos conforme al dispositivo)  lo voy  a añadir a la pregunta!

Comment: no se que quiere decir codigo sucio.. pero no entiendo porque cada control no tiene su propio control de los botones, y de ahi ya sabes que dato tiene cada control. No entiendo como manejas esa informacion, ni porque los eventos de los botones estan afuera.. de paso, tampoco veo que controles que control lanzo el evento, de ninguna manera....

Comment: Buenas tardes; probaré lo de usar cada evento de control dentro de su control. Con código sucio me refiero a que todas las variables del control las tengo sin organizar ni encapsuladas ni nada sólo para probar su función; etc. Probaré añadiendo mejor el código de la clase entera del control